# Is socket programming (in java) applicable for Wide Area Network

Tags: java

Can we use the socket class in java to communicate over a Wide Area Network?

Comment: Your question is incomplete, but yes, you can use socket to communicate on WAN (basically, a Web Server contains Server Sockets to communicate over a WAN). It would be good if you also post what you really need, maybe there is a Java technology that can help you with your functional requirement development.

Comment: Short answer: Yes, of course.  Why not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can generally do any socket programming in Java that you can do in any other language.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani - can you show me a reference in the site documentation as to why that's so? My understanding is that comments are for questions to clarify the question, not for answers. Short as it is, it's an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sockets over LANs, VLANs, MANs, WANs in Java or any other language.